# apply a function to a data frame and include a new column from the second dataframe to the first dataframe, of differing sizes in R

Tags: r, apply

I am new to R and was wondering what is the best way to do the following -

My actual problem is a multivariate regression model but its a fairly large dataset(>5000 rows and 12 columns) and hence I've designed an analogous shorter problem. The solution to the below problem can be replicated to solve my actual problem. Any help(including speed issues) on the below will be greatly appreciated-
I have the following two data frames-d1 and d2

```
d1 -
   sno letter age
   1      a  29
   2      b  30
   3      a  33
   4      b  22
   5      c  25
d2-
  letter marks
     a    40
     b    90
     c    60
```

Now , I want to calculate whether a,b,c have passed or failed from d2 using marks_code and then include the corresponding grades in d1. So my final output should look like this-

```
d1 -
   sno letter age grade
   1      a  29     0
   2      b  30     1
   3      a  33     0
   4      b  22     1
   5      c  25     1
```

Below is the code I wrote-(I'm not getting the result I want!)

```
d1 <- data.frame(cbind(1:5,c("a","b","a","b","c"),c(29,30,33,22,25)),stringsAsFactors=FALSE )
colnames(d1) <- c("sno","letter","age")

d2 <- data.frame(cbind(c("a","b","c"),c(40,90,60)),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
colnames(d2) <- c("letter","marks")

d2$grade <- rep(NA,3) #initialising the vector
d2$grade <- sapply(d2$marks,marks_code)
d1$grade <- rep(NA,5)
d1_coding(d1$letter)

d1_coding <- function(y1)
{
  letter_names <- unique(y1)
  m <- length(letter_names)
  for(i in 1:m)
  {
    sub <- subset(d1,d1$letter==letter_name[i])
    num_obs <- length(sub$sno)
    sub$grade <- rep(d2$grade[i],num_obs)
    merge(d1,sub,by="sno")
  }
 return(d1) 
}

marks_code <- function(y)
{
  a <-NA
  if(y<=40)
    a <- 0#fail
  else
    a<- 1#pass
  return(a)
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
d1 <- as.data.table(d1)
d2 <- as.data.table(d2)
setkey(d1, "letter")
setkey(d2, "letter")
out <- d2[d1][, grade := (marks > 40) * 1]
setcolorder(out, c("letter", "sno", "age", "marks", "grade"))

 #    letter sno age marks grade
 # 1:      a   1  29    40     0
 # 2:      a   3  33    40     0
 # 3:      b   2  30    90     1
 # 4:      b   4  22    90     1
 # 5:      c   5  25    60     1
```

---

If you want the same order, you can set key back to "sno" as:

```
setkey(out, "sno")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ifelse` for this because unlike `if` it is vectorized.

```
d1 <- read.table(text="  sno letter age
1      a  29
2      b  30
3      a  33
4      b  22
5      c  25",header=TRUE)

d2 <- read.table(text="  letter marks
a    40
b    90
c    60",header=TRUE)

res <- merge(d1,d2)
res$grade <- ifelse(res$marks <= 40, 0, 1)

res <- res[order(res$sno),]

#   letter sno age marks grade
# 1      a   1  29    40     0
# 3      b   2  30    90     1
# 2      a   3  33    40     0
# 4      b   4  22    90     1
# 5      c   5  25    60     1
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Its quite a terse way of doing this. I think I can do the same for the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach:

```
d1$grade <- 
as.numeric(sapply(d1$letter, FUN=function(z) d2[d2$letter==z,"marks"]>40))
```

And another, without `sapply`:

```
d1$grade <- 
as.numeric(d2$marks[pmatch(d1$letter, d2$letter, duplicates.ok=TRUE)] > 40)
```

Comment: This uses an unnecessary loop.

Comment: Yea, that was a first step. I added a second version.